# Minecraft server with forge does not boot

Tags: minecraft

Hello good I am doing a minecraft server version 1.18.2 with forge 4.1.67, the thing is that when I try to boot the server returns me killed, in many places I have seen that what they do is assign more ram, I right now I have assigned a minimum of 4 and a maximum of 8 in a debian server where only this minecraft server is hosted,   the command they use isthe command they use is:

```
java -Xms5G -Xmx6G -XshowSettings:all -jar forgeserver.jar nogui
```

Once this is done I check that the installation is fine before inserting the mods, the problem is that it returns this to me:

[image: Error]

Comment: You should resolve the first warning with regards to the incorrect configuration file, `forge-server.toml`, that likely will resolve the majority of the warnings.

Comment: Again, post the log messages as text and *not* a screenshot. Also, use code formatting (and not block quote formatting) to format the log text.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of the OOM (Out of memory killer) which kills processes which are using all the RAM. You should open another terminal, and type `dmesg -w`, then execute the minecraft server and wait for an output in `dmesg`.

If the OOM Killer is getting triggered by the Java process (the minecraft server), it should say something like this:

```
Out of memory: kill process [PID number] (run.sh) score [random number] or a child
```

and

```
Killed process [PID number] (java)
```

If you get this after booting the minecraft server, your system doesn't have enough RAM to handle the server - it could be because a mod is using a lot of memory or having a memory leak.

How to solve it?:

- Add more RAM to the server
- Assign a bigger Swap space to the server (if the minecraft server is using more Swap space than the RAM, it can lead to slowdowns, very annoying stutters and slow chunk loading because the Swap space is much slower than RAM)

A related problem which also involves Java: [Something keeps killing my Java process on Ubuntu, anyone know why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146152/something-keeps-killing-my-java-process-on-ubuntu-anyone-know-why)

Comment: I'm testing it, but I recommend changing the command from 'desmg' to 'dmesg'